# is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'

Tags: function, closures

I have the following distribution function (F):

```
F<-function(t) {
if(any(t>=0)) (1+ (-1)/(1+t^2)) else (0)
}
```

When plotting, it looks as follows:

```
plot(Vectorize(F), xlim=c(-100,100), main="Distribution function", xlab="t", ylab="F(t)")
```

[image: Distribution Function]

I am trying to calculate the 0.25,0.75 and 0.50 quantiles for this F distribution, but I get the following error message:

```
quantile(F, probs = seq(0.25, 0.5,0.75))
```

> Error in quantile.default(F, probs = seq(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) : 
>       anyNA() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'

Also, the following code doesn't work either:

```
quantile(F, probs = seq(0.25, 0.50, 0.75), na.rm = TRUE)
```

> Error in x[!is.na(x)] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'

I can not get to solve the problem. 
Could anyone one tell me how to fix it?

Thank you